# Querying Parent-Child relationship in a consecutive way

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I'm trying to write an import tool to convert my database from one schema to another.

So now I've come across a table that uses a Parent-Child relationship (via PK `ID` FK `ParentID`) and I want to select all records consecutively.

The risk of my query is that I might try to import a child element, whose parent element is not already imported. This would result in a recordset that's not going to be imported and is therefore to avoid.

My query I've worked on is as following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table a INNER JOIN Table b ON (b.ParentID=a.ID and a.ID= b.ParentID)
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work (it doesn't give me all the records in the table), so I need a query that gives me all rows in the table, ordered by child and parent elements, that I just can loop over to import.

Can someone guide me the way?

Comment: The `and` clause in your query is not necessary, since it's the same in both cases. But in a case such as this, I would probably first import all `parent` records, and then all `child` records, so something like `import into TableB select * from Table where ParentID is null` then `import into TableB select * from Table where ParentID is not null`.

Comment: I thought of something like that, too. But that doesn't work since the inheritance depth is more than 1. So a child element might be the parent element of another child element.

Comment: But there must be some absolute-parent elements, no? Elements that are not children themselves? If that's the case then you could still run the first query, then run something like the following repeatedly until you get all the records: `insert into TableB select * from Table where ParentID is not null and exists (select 1 from TableB where ID = Table.ParentID)`

Comment: @beercodebeer Sure, some absolute-parents do exist, I was just hoping to get that done in one query instead of multiple ones.

Comment: I don't think you could do that without first removing the foreign key constraint on your new table. If you did that, then you could probably import all the records at once, and then re-apply the foreign key constraint afterward. Optionally, you could import all the records, but keep `ParentID null` on your second table, and then run an update query: `update TableB set ParentID = (select ParentID from Table where ID = TableB.ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a recursive common table expression which can be found at this link:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

You can use this to tell your downstream ETL the sequence things should be loaded in. For instance, all 1's go first and 2's second and so on.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
ID INT,
ParentId INT)

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
    (1, 0),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 0),
    (5, 4),
    (6, 4),
    (7, 1),
    (8, 7)

--This is the anchor query and selects top level records
;WITH cte_Recursive AS (
    SELECT ID, ParentId, 1 [Depth]
    FROM @Table
    WHERE ParentId = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.ID, T.ParentId
        ,R.Depth + 1 [Depth]
    FROM @Table T
    INNER JOIN cte_Recursive R ON R.ID = T.ParentId
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_Recursive
```

Comment: Now this is exactly what I wanted... And now I even know what it's called. Thanks! :)